# Unknown root level key: locals

Tags: terraform

I'm running Terraform v0.9.11 (don't ask why) and, following this:

https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/locals.html

My module code is:

```
locals {
    default_name_prefix = "${var.project_name}-web"
}

resource "aws_instance" "module_instance" {
  ami  = "<my ami>"
}
```

but I'm running into this error:

```
terraform plan
1 error(s) occurred:

* module root: 1 error(s) occurred:

* Unknown root level key: locals
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Locals were released in [Terraform 0.10.3](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#0103-august-30-2017).

If you want to use them you will need to use a more recent version of Terraform.

Comment: I see a bugfix for 0.10.3 but not anything about them being released then. Do you have anything to confirm?

Comment: It's under "New Features" for 0.10.3. The author also notes the release version in his PR: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/pull/15449#issuecomment-338417830

Comment: https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/hashicorp-terraform-0-11#per-module-provider-configuration also mentions that they were released in 0.10.3.